# open screen/view (iPhone app)

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, ios4, soap

I have a iOS developer.  He is writing he iPhone app.
I am writing the web service that is used by the iPhone app.

The mobile app has many screens (or views what do you call it?)

What response does my web service need to respond with so that the mobile app knows what screen to open. There are many screens, and different screen input parameters.

**Note:** im not an objective-c developer. So I dont know what my developer wants my web service to respond with.

Comment: Have you asked your developer?

Comment: not yet, she is not in this week, will ask her next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on requirement you don't need to do anything with screens(views). This depends on Requirement of the project. What data has o be displayed for a specific screen you need to create functions for that only. The developer will call your web service function and your web service will return response in format of json(I prefer because it's lightweight and fast) or XML. The ios developer will parse the response and display the data on screen. Now it's up to him how he uses your web services. For example assume there is login screen so iphone app will send you user name and password your web service validate the credential and send response as success or failure. I hope you understand.

Comment: Actually the mobile app gets notification list, it response with a string content:"You just received a message from Bob" then the mobile app should open the message screen. OR "Alex invites you to Event X" then the mobile app should open the event screen.

Comment: it's depend upon your developer. you just need to do what i told you

Answer (score 2):

ASK YOUR DEVELOPER! (and they're called views). Someone developing a web service shouldn't be worried about views, that's definitely a dev issue